# Parse Notification not working in Android

Tags: android

Parse notification not receiving in android app from Parse Server.

In Below link it shown notification is not sent with Push sent 0 on parse serve

https://www.parse.com/apps/bluejay-test/push_notifications/mmBUWvc8US

Also in Parse Account Client push enabled is Yes.

I am sending the push notification from parse cloud server its not receiving in android APP but receive in ios APP .Its sometime come in android mobile.

Please suggest me what is the issue?

In Login User Time, I am using this code

```
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().put("uuid",user.getUuid());
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().put("email",parseUser.getEmail());
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().put("uuid",user.getUuid());
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
@Override
                public void done(ParseException arg0) {

                                 }});
```

and also also followed all the trouble shooting steps and added the configuration in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<permission
        android:name="com.redblink.bluejay.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.redblink.bluejay.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver
            android:name="com.redblink.bluejay.CustomParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                 <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                    <category android:name="com.redblink.bluejay" />


            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I have added the CustomParsePushBroadcastReceiver for receiving the notification

```
public class CustomParsePushBroadcastReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
    private String TAG ="CustomParsePushBroadcastReceiver"    ;
    BlueJayApplication application;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        BlueJayApplication application = (BlueJayApplication) context.getApplicationContext();

        Bundle e = intent.getExtras();

        for (String key : e.keySet()) {

            BluejayDebug.Log(TAG, "Extra: " + key);
            BluejayDebug.Log(TAG, "" + e.getString(key));
        }

        BluejayNotificationManager.Init(context);
        BluejayNotificationManager.getInstance().sendGenericNotification("BlueJay", "New bluejay event");

    }

    public void setApplication(){


    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see anything in Logcat and you should post here as well so that we can assist you better

Answer (score 0):

Modify this

```
   <receiver
        android:name="com.redblink.bluejay.CustomParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

To this

```
<receiver android:name="com.redlink.bluejay.CustomParsePushBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: I have modified the xml file with this code but not receiving the notification in Android APP.                                                                                           <receiver android:name="com.redlink.bluejay.CustomParsePushBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

Answer (score 0):

The function you should be overriding is onPushReceive() not onReceive(). Change the function and that will fix the issue.

The documentation explains that. 
https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: I have changed the function from onReceive() to onPushReceive() .But the issue is not fixed yet.Please help me for resolving this issue